# Type 2 Slowly Changing Dimensions and Querying for Historical data at a point in time

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have a small star schema representing time entries for issues in Jira. I have an IssueAttributes type 2 dimension table, and then a TimeEntry fact table.

Simplified view of dimension table:

```
+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| IssueKey | IssueID | IssueNumber | IssueName | IsCurrent | ValidFrom  | ValidTo  |
+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| 1        | 123456  | PR-1000     | Original  |  0        | 2000-01-01 |2020-04-09|
+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
| 2        | 123456  | PR-1000     | Changed   |  1        | 2020-04-10 |9999-1231 |
+----------+---------+-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Simplified view of Fact Table:

```
+--------------+---------+-----------+
| TimeEntryKey | IssueKey| TimeEntry |
+--------------+---------+-----------+
| 11111        | 1       | 1.25      |
+--------------+---------+-----------+
| 11112        | 2       | 1.5       |
+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

When I'm inserting into the fact table, I'm using whatever is the current `IssueKey` from the dimension table, which seems like the right approach. But if I want to get a SUM of the time entries and group them by the `IssueName`, it would result in 2 rows as the name has changed between the first and second rows. I'm under the impression that it's best to keep simple joins and use the keys, but in this instance it seems like you'd need to first join to the Dimension on the `IssueKey`, and then join that to the dimension again on the `IssueNumber` and `IsCurrent = 1` in order to get the attributes for the current version of data. I have no problem doing this, but I'm also under the understanding that joins should be simple in a DW so the end user doesn't have to think through how those joins work, and this seems to contradict that understanding. Am I thinking about this correctly? You're not supposed to go back and update the FKs in the fact table, right? Do I need a conformed dimension or something to keep certain attributes consistent over time?

My current approach is to put the gymnastics in a view so the end user can just reference the view and doesn't have to think through all the joins. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Hi Hyphen  Is your fact table maintaining history?

Comment: @NITHINB my fact records are inserted with the key to the current version of the dimension record at the time of insert and then I’m not updating that fact record again. So in my example the fact record with TimeEntryKey 11111 never gets updated to reflect IssueKey 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your TimeEntry fact is a transactional fact table. I would suggest you add the following columns

- row current flag
- start date (or 'start date time' if you would have more than one updates during the day )
- end date (or 'end date time' if you would have more than one updates during the day)

Now when you do aggregation, you would need to only look at the current rows in the fact table; your latest rows will also only look at the latest dim rows which you have already implemented. You would also not have to go and update a historical record in case there is a change in the source system. You might need to retire the old rows and add a new row with keys to the latest attribute.

This might solve your problem.

Comment: I had considered doing this, but it doesn't seem common to have a type 2 fact table, so I was second guessing myself. I haven't had any other ideas and the type 2 fact table seems like it would solve the problem, so I think I'll go with this approach.